# How to highlight a settings row in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin

I'm trying to implement the fingerprint authentication and I want to make the user register a new fingerprint if He hasn't one. I know how to start an Intent to the Security Settings menu, but I can't find anywhere how to highlight the option I want the user to click. Do you think it's possible?
Thanks for your help

Comment: you want to highlight the menu that your intent opens???

Comment: well, not the menu itself, but the single row, for example in my case in security settings, the row that needs to be highlighted is Fingerprint

Comment: that cannot be done I guess, just show them a long toast with audio instruction. Find some way to tell your users what they should be looking for in the menu, that's all you can do or get your app to draw over the screen and show some hint

Comment: yes, I think I'll use your strategy. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting Android P and higher, you can take the user 1 step further with the specific Intent `Settings.ACTION_FINGERPRINT_ENROLL`.

You can use this way:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
private void startFingerprintEnrollment(@NonNull AppCompatActivity activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_FINGERPRINT_ENROLL);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE_FINGERPRINT_ENROLLMENT);
}
```

For lower versions you can use what you're already using. Unfortunately there is no way to **highlight** the specific Setting row.

Comment: Thanks, I already knew that Action, but it brings directly to "Insert PIN" and I think some users may be disappointed or confused. I asked this question because I remember some apps guiding the user into many settings voices, with 2 or 3 clicks.